# Hibernate: how to create and execute sql procedure via jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto option

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a couple of stored procedures that I want to execute as initial setup. So What I have done, placed that stored procedure in `data.sql` and set the `jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`.

But on startup of my `springboot` application, the application is failing with **com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException**. It means, it is not able to understand the syntax of that procedure, however the same procedure can be executed manually on `sql` sheet without any problem. So how can I execute it via `data.sql`

**data.sql** -

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `GetStocks`(int_stockcode varchar(20))
BEGIN
  DECLARE stock_name VARCHAR(100);
  SELECT name FROM stock where stock_code = int_stockcode INTO stock_name;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

**error**-

> Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException:
>
> Failed to execute SQL script statement #29 of class path resource [default-data.sql]: DELIMITER $$ CREATE PROCEDURE `GetStocks`(int_stockcode varchar(20)) BEGIN SELECT * FROM stock where stock_code = int_stockcode; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE PROCEDURE `GetStocks`(int_stockcode varchar(20)) BEGIN SELEC' at line 1
>
> at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:491)
>     at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:238)
>     at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:48)
>     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:192)
>     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runDataScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:128)
>     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializer.java:118)
>     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.onApplicationEvent(DataSourceInitializer.java:51)
>     at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
>     at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347)
>     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:77)
>     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:68)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1775)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:113)
>     ... 75 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE PROCEDURE `GetStocks`(int_stockcode varchar(20)) BEGIN SELEC' at line 1
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor71.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2444)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:845)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:745)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.execute(Unknown Source)
>     at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:470)
>       ... 90 common frames omitted

Comment: Can you please add the whole stacktrace?

Comment: Edited question to show whole stacktrace

Comment: Seems the driver is not respecting the delimiter.You can try looking at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56483637/create-mysql-stored-procedure-using-jpa-hibernate/56484367#56484367   and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989767/how-to-create-a-mysql-stored-procedure-in-a-jdbctemplate/56990223#56990223

Comment: Sorry that answer in the thread does not seem working

Comment: Could you post the error what you are getting after applying that fix?

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #29 of class path resource [default-data.sql]: CREATE PROCEDURE GetStocks(int_stockcode varchar(20) BEGIN DECLARE stock_name  VARCHAR(100); nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Did you removed the DELIMITER, $$ and DELIMITER; from the script and tested?

Comment: Yes, I tried removing DELIMITER.........  CREATE PROCEDURE `GetStocks`(int_stockcode varchar(20))
BEGIN
  DECLARE stock_name VARCHAR(100);
  SELECT name FROM stock where stock_code = int_stockcode INTO stock_name;
END;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For loading and creating the database objects it is better to stick to liquibase or flyway.
Using the following code it is possible to load the stored procedure.

Used a controller to load the stored procedure but it can be a simple class or can be configured via an event listener.

```
@RestController
public class SqlLoaderController {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @GetMapping("/load")
    public void loadScript() throws Exception
    {

        ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator=new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        resourceDatabasePopulator.setSeparator("DELIMITER");
        InputStream is= new ClassPathResource("sql.txt").getInputStream();
        resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(new InputStreamResource(is));
        resourceDatabasePopulator.execute(dataSource);

    }
}
```

The DELIMITER is used to distinguish between start and end of two stored procedure or database objects.The sql.txt file

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetStocks(int_stockcode varchar(20))
BEGIN
  DECLARE stock_name VARCHAR(100);
  SELECT 1 FROM dual;
END;

DELIMITER

CREATE PROCEDURE GetStocks1(int_stockcode varchar(20))
BEGIN
  DECLARE stock_name VARCHAR(100);
  SELECT 1 FROM dual;
END;
DELIMITER
```